# Azure Private Link - delete private link does not appear to work properly

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am working with the Private Link preview feature. I was able to get it configured properly and working as expected over an ExpressRoute circuit. I then needed to move it to another subnet as the subnet it was on required a Microsoft Storage endpoint.

Since service endpoints and private links cannot exist on the same subnet I decided to delete the private link and set up the service endpoint. The private link seemed to delete successfully and no longer showed in the portal.

The problem is when I went to set up the service endpoint Azure thinks there are still private links configured on the subnet and the creation of the service endpoint fails. Anyone seen this before and/or how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same issue that it seems currently it's impossible to restore the subnet to enable service endpoints once you have started a private link to an Azure service like storage account in the same subnet even I have removed the private links, private DNS zone, storage account, etc.

You could request a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback?query=private%20link) to improve this product as the [Azure private link is in preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview).

> Important
>
> This public preview is provided without a service level agreement and
>   should not be used for production workloads. **Certain features may not
>   be supported, may have constrained capabilities, or may not be
>   available in all Azure locations**. See the Supplemental Terms of Use
>   for Microsoft Azure Previews for details. For known limitations, see
>   Private Endpoint and Private Link Service.

### Update

I have contacted MSFT PG, they said that

This is a known limitation documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#limitations), they are working on removing limitation by the end of October.